# My compiler doesn't create an exe file, then tries to run it?

Tags: c++

I just installed msys64 and added my compiler to the path on VSCode. Now when I try to run it file it says:

```
Starting build...
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\idkbo\OneDrive\Masaüstü\cpptest\tgame\test.cpp -o C:\Users\idkbo\OneDrive\Masaüstü\cpptest\tgame\test.exe 
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file C:\Users\idkbo\OneDrive\Masaüstü\cpptest\tgame\test.exe: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I couldn't do anything because there were no errors like this on any coding platform.

Please help me as I am stuck in this error for awhile.

Comment: Can you run the exe manually? Please show your build commands. Can you compile it from command-line? What if you put it into some folder with ASCII-only path, no `ü`.

Comment: I can, I don't really know I Just pressed run button on vs code, yes. I cant, nothing will change since I already tried that.

Comment: @Fsd I suggest you try and run the compiler manually. Open a console window and type in the `g++ ...` command above. Do you see any compilation or linker errors then?

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that the unicode character `ü` is confusing the compiler path. Also having your builds save to your OneDrive folder will just generate unnecessary upload churn. Perhaps you can change your project directory to a local folder (e.g. `C:\Code`)

Comment: When I try to run it manually it says undefined reference to winmain.

Comment: Let's add `-Wall -Wextra` to your command line, e.g. `C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/g++.exe -Wall -Wextra ...` to enable warnings which may further shed light on what is happening during your build. The link fails (`ld returned 1 exit`), so you never compiled the program.

Comment: @fsd It seems (I'm no expert) that error means that your code lacks a `main` function. The other issue of course is why you don't see that error in VSCode, maybe you aren't looking in the right place? VSCode is an extremely tricky program to set up correctly. I would never suggest it for a beginner.

Comment: No, it doesn't try to run your executable. There are non-ASCII characters in the path. Your compiler and your OS may have different ideas about them.  Try using only ASCII in your paths.

Comment: @n.m. The OS is clearly Windows (see reference to OneDrive) I'd be surprised if Windows couldn't handle non-ASCII file paths. But agreed, it is one more thing to eliminate.

Comment: @john It can of course, but it uses UTF-16 AFAIK which might confuse cygwin ports of gcc,g++ since Linux uses UTF-8. But not sure, just worth trying.

Comment: @fsd In that case I think your launch.json or whatever VScode uses needs tweaking. VSCode does not have IMHO beginner-friendly setup. But it has plenty of documentation online, you should be able to piece together a working setup.

Comment: Please show us your code, we're all taking pot shots in the dark here.  Add it to your question, not as a comment.  Thanks.

Comment: @PaulSanders There is no need to show any code. "ld.exe: cannot open output file" cannot possibly be a result of anything whatsoever in the code.

Comment: @n.m Good point!  my attention was actually captured by "When I try to run [the compiler] manually it says undefined reference to `winmain`", so that's also going to be a problem, once the first one is fixed.

Comment: @PaulSanders well this one has more duplicates than I care to count.

Comment: @n.m. Fair enough although this is a weird one, the entry point for Win32 GUI apps should be `WinMain`, not `winmain`.  Maybe it's an msys thing, I never use that.  Or maybe the OP is [trying to] write a console app.  Anyway, should probably be a separate question either way, OP please take note.